# Energy of photon from superposition to ground state

Tags: energy, photons, superposition

Let an atom is in superposition of two eigen energy states E1 and E2. If it returns to the ground level E0 what energy should have the photon released in the process?

Answer (score 1):

The emitted photon is a superposition of a photon with energy $\Delta E_1 = E_1 - E_0$ and a photon with energy $\Delta E_2 = E_2 - E_0$. If you send it through a prism the two parts of the superposition split into two different paths. 
If you place a detector in each of the possible paths only one of them will detect a photon. Assuming the detector in the path corresponding to the energy $\Delta E_1$ detected it, the superposition of states collapses to the detected one. This means that the whole system of atom and photon behaved as if it had been in the state with energy $E_1$ in the beginning.

Comment: This is incorrect according to the Born rule.

Comment: @my2cts Where do you see the contradiction? Born's rule just quantifies the probabilities for the outcomes.

Comment: @A.P. you see my previous remark under my2cts answer? Crucial here is the interference of the two paths when they overlap!

Comment: @Mercury Yes, they do interfere. But the interference pattern oscillates at a frequency $\frac{|\Delta E_1 - \Delta E_2|}{\hbar}$.

Comment: @my2cts The Born rule just gives the different probabilities for any outcome and one has here two outcomes connected to Energy.

Comment: @A.P. Why does it oscillate? I suppose because the energies in the paths are different (hence wavelength) but I can not figure out why right away. Where did you get the formulae? And what does oscillation mean in the case? The photons can come at arbitrary times one by one. The different wavelengths are problematic for the interference anyway, which I didn't realize at first.

Comment: @Mercury The two parts of the photon wavepacket have different frequencies $\frac{\Delta E_1}{\hbar}$ and $\frac{\Delta E_2}{\hbar}$. [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) describes well what happens when two waves of different frequency are superimposed. This is true for acoustic, for electromagnetic as well as quantum waves.

Comment: @A.P. One can also change one wavelength and get a steady interference pattern maybe.

Answer (score 0):

It can be E$_1$-E$_0$ or E$_2$-E$_0$. The probability for each is determined by the dipole matrix element $\langle \psi_i | \vec r | \psi_0 \rangle$ and the coefficients of the mixed state.

Comment: If the photon's energy is E1-E0 or E2-E0 - one or the other than the atom can not have been in superposition of E1 and E2. Is it not that the photon should be in superposition of both energies? And when going throught a prism it would take both paths and interfere with itself when the paths overlap?